# Android application published on market

Tags: android, google-play

I just published my application on the market but I can't find it out. Does it take a while before I can find it on the market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can indeed take a while. It can be instant, 30 minutes or even an hour. Just be patient :)

Comment: patient solve many problems :)

Comment: Yes, I found it. Thanks. Now I have an other problem. How could I change the default icon that appears in the left in android market?

Comment: Can you post the link to your app?

Comment: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.quizcontest.alex